# How can I order a mySQL column by a number imbedded in a string?

Tags: mysql, regex

I am parsing genomic positions from a MySQL field. The field is called "change" and the entries are of the form:

```
g.100214985T>C 
g.100249769C>A
g.10185G>T
```

I am trying to order the field by the numerical portion of the string. I am trying to figure out what mySQL query I can use to accomplish this. I have tried using REGEXPs and SUBSTRING_INDEX but am still running into issues. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have always 2 characters in front of and 3 at the end you need to have removed:

```
SELECT CAST(SUBSTR(col from 3) AS UNSIGNED) AS value 
FROM `my_table`
ORDER BY value
```

Watch this sql fiddle also: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7bc0e/67

Comment: I gues it is more easy to read, but it is actually longer in text length isn't it?

Comment: I misread that. I guess, I meant, shorten it to `CAST(SUBSTR(\`field\`, 3) AS UNSIGNED)`. MySQL already stops the conversion at the first non-numerical character.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @MarcusAdams and @amoudhgz! The following code works:

`CAST(SUBSTR(field, 3) AS UNSIGNED)`.

MySQL already stops the conversion at the first non-numerical character.